# Chrome Extension: adding button to header-title area of tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

I want to develop extension that can reload a web page by clicking on the tub.

[image: example]

Is it possible to add a button to the title area of a web page?

If yes

1. What should I add to the manifest?
2. Which object should I use to do so?

Comment: To change the UI in that wat, you may need a theme: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide

Comment: I don't thing that a theme can effect the content of the a page nor can make a tab clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **this is not possible**. The Google Chrome Extension APIs do not provide any functionality to do this... yet. As of now, your extension can only display page actions on the address bar or browser actions near it along with other extensions.

[**Page actions**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction):

[image: page actions]

[**Browser actions**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction):

[image: browser actions]